# Had a problem realizing a simple head function in Linux using c language

Tags: c

I have managed to realize the -n function, but I am having problem realizing the -c function which prints out n bytes of the content in the file.

Here is my code so far:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    char ch;            //Define command indicator.

    FILE *fp = NULL;    //Define file position pointer.

    char buff[255];     //Define buffer and size.

    int line = 10, byte;    //Define initial number of lines and the number of bytes.

    printf("--------------------------\n");

    while ((ch = getopt(argc, argv, "n:c:")) != -1)     //Read command.
    {
        switch (ch)
        {
            case 'n':       //if -n, change the number of lines to user input.
                line = atoi(optarg);
                break;
            case 'c':       //if - c, change the number  of bytes to user input.
                byte = atoi(optarg);
                break;
            case '?':       //if option not included, print out error message.
                printf("Unknown option: %c\n",(char)optopt);
                exit(1);

        }
    }

    fp = fopen(argv[argc - 1], "r");    //open file and point fp to the file location which user inputted.

    if (fp == NULL)     //if pointer fp doesn't exist, print out error message.
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "File can not be opened.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= line; i++)     //print out n lines of file context.
    {
        fgets(buff, 255, (FILE *) fp);
        if (feof(fp))           //if reached end of file, exit if loop.
        {
            break;
        }
        printf("%d: %s\n", i, buff);
    }

    fclose(fp);     //close file

    return 0;
}
```

I have absolutely no idea how to proceed forward with the -c case, I have tried to put the for loop and fopen() into case ‘c’ but that returns error message that file cannot be opened.

Comment: Note that like basically all character-returning functions in C, the [`getopt`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getopt.3.html) function returns an **`int`**. This is actually rather important because `char` might actually be *unsigned* in which case the comparison with `-1` will not work as expected.

Comment: You should also check what [`fgets` *returns*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets#Return_value) rather than check `feof`. `feof` will return a false negative if there's another error reading the input.

Comment: And if `fp` have the type `FILE *`, why do you cast `fp` to `FILE *`?

Comment: As for your problem, I suggest you create two functions: One to read *lines* of input, which you call in the `-n` case; And another to read *bytes* of input, which you call in the `-c` case. In the `-c` case read character by character until the counter, or until `EOF` (but again remember that the functions that read characters return an **`int`**).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.